# PHP: Modify array's elements sequence

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've an php array that I've got from Excel file, for example:

#### $arrayOne

```
Array
{
 [0] => Array
       {
        [0] => 0_age
        [1] => 1_academic id
        [2] => 2_name
        [3] => 3_sex
       }
 [1] => Array
       {
        [0] => 0_18
        [1] => 1_110291
        [2] => 2_Jason
        [3] => 3_Male
       }
  }
```

and in the mid of proccess, the array value from index `[0]` that consist data from *Excel Header* set into duallistbox for elimination and sorting then set into new array `$newArray`. So then, I got this array result:

#### $newArray

```
Array
{
 [0] => Array
       {
        [0] => 2_name
        [1] => 1_academic id
        [2] => 3_sex
       }
 }
```

And I expect the system also can eliminate and sorting the data of array from index `[1]` that consist of *Excel Data*.
So the expected result is like this:

#### $expectedArray

```
Array
{
 [0] => Array
       {
        [0] => 2_Jason
        [1] => 1_110291
        [2] => 3_Male
       }
 }
```

anyone know idea or how to solve this case? I've add an **id(e.g: 0_)** in each of array value that maybe useful for sorting.
Thanks

### Edited

The sorting is based on the **id** that have been set on each value of array, so each element on array index `[1]` from `$arrayOne` is reset into new sequence adapted to same **id** from `$newArray`.

Comment: Are you looking for this? please see the link  : stackoverflow.com/questions/9043888/multidimensional-array-sort-on-multiple-keys

Comment: @Shan I dont think so, I've updated the question, you can see more explanation in **Edited** label, please check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**One way**

```
    <?php
$arr = array(
 array
       (
        "0_age",
        "1_academic id",
        "2_name",
        "3_sex",
       ),
 array
       (
        "0_18",
        "1_110291",
        "2_Jason",
        "3_Male",
       ),
    array
       (
        "0_28",
        "1_110291111",
        "2_Jason Second",
        "3_Female",
       )
  );

?>
<pre>
<?php 
$new_array = array();
$count = 0;
foreach($arr as $a){
    if($count==0){

    }else{
        $new_array[] = array(
            $arr[0][0] => $a[0],
            $arr[0][1] => $a[1],
            $arr[0][2] => $a[2],
            $arr[0][3] => $a[3],
        );
    }

    $count=$count+1;
}
print_r($new_array);
?>
</pre>
```

**Output**

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0_age] => 0_18
            [1_academic id] => 1_110291
            [2_name] => 2_Jason
            [3_sex] => 3_Male
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0_age] => 0_28
            [1_academic id] => 1_110291111
            [2_name] => 2_Jason Second
            [3_sex] => 3_Female
        )

)
```

**Second Way that exactly match with your output**

```
    $new_array = array();
$count = 0;
foreach($arr as $a){
    if($count==0){

    }else{
        $new_array[] = array(
            //$a[0],
            $a[2],
            $a[1],
            $a[3],
        );
    }

    $count=$count+1;
}
print_r($new_array);
```

**Output:**

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0_18
            [1] => 1_110291
            [2] => 2_Jason
            [3] => 3_Male
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0_28
            [1] => 1_110291111
            [2] => 2_Jason Second
            [3] => 3_Female
        )

)
```

You can search, Sort and remove any field. Update on the basis of your requirement.

Comment: Hi @shaileshsingh, thanks for your help. I think my `$arrayOne` above is same with your second way output. But actually what I need is how to modify the array index `[1]` from `$arrayOne` has form look like `$newArray` based on their **id[e.g: _1]**, so at the final I can get result look like `$expectedArray`.

Comment: do want to remove that index numbers and just want age, name etc as index and their corresponding value.:. what you want as final result from your i put array? please comment your final output that you want. you clarify your input and output please.

Comment: now try the second way and i have updated the code... try and comment if that is what you want sir.

Comment: My fault, sorry. I've tried but got me a crash. But I think it should be work, and I think your code work staticly. How if I need proccess dinamically, the sequence can be changes as needed.